# Average function on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the average function in a loop,which calculate the average of amounts for a same client per month ( its not a monthly average, it only consider the open days) and it works perfectly on a 5000 lines sheet, but ones i used it in a 56703 lines sheet, it didn't work so well, and misses some clients. Why does it do that ? how can i fix it

```
    Sub calcav()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim a As Integer

   Sheets("Source").Activate
   a = 2
   i = 2
   While Cells(i, 6) <> ""
   j = i
      While Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i + 1, 6) And Month(Cells(i, 18)) =Month(Cells(i + 1, 18))
   i = i + 1
      Wend
    Sheets("Average").Cells(a, 1) = Cells(i, 6).Value
    Sheets("Average").Cells(a, 2) = Month(Cells(i, 18))
    Sheets("Average").Cells(a, 3) = Year(Cells(i, 18))
    Sheets("Average").Cells(a, 4)   =Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("V" & j & ":V" & i))
    Sheets("Average").Cells(a, 5) = Left(Cells(i, 20).Value, 3)
    a = a + 1

   i = i + 1
   Wend

   End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use a PivotTable?

Comment: Are you sure your variable a does not exceed 32,767 on large sheets as it is defined as Integer?

Comment: @LS_dev, I can't use a PivotTable, this task should be automatized and in a spécifique format @ Maartenvan Stam, no it doesn't exceed 2000 lines, I just tried Long definition, i still have the same problem

Comment: how does it behave badly ? does it just skip the Clients, or what wrong results are you getting ?

Comment: it just skip the client yes and dont reflect it in the result sheet, like it doesn't exist.

Comment: ok since it also skips the a = a+1 part, it has to be in the line While Cells(i, 6) <> "". this should work, but try to replace it with While Cells(i, 6).value <> vbNullString  maybe it is a strange vba bug

Comment: @DoktorOswaldo, i found the problem, some clients had no names only ID Codes, so when ever the macro found "NA" it add it to the first ID Code, i missed up choosing my Key, thanks for lighting that up.